# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor not able to schedule multiple http request url jobs

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-admin

Requirement: Need to launch spring batch job in parallel and schedule the same.

Job will be launched using http request url and after the launch it will be scheduled as per cron expression. I have added ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in the joblauncher but the second job is overlapping the first one and only one job is getting scheduled. In short i need to launch the jobs asynchronously but it is running synchronously. Is there anything i am missing?

Launcher file:

```
@Path("/user-management")
public class UserManagementModule {
    String springConfig = "spring/batch/jobs/job-report.xml";

    @GET
    @Path("/users/{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response getUserById(@PathParam("id") Integer id)
            throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
            JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException, IOException {

        ApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = (SimpleJobLauncher)        context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("reportJob");
        JobExecution executionall = jobLauncher.run(
                    job,
                    new JobParametersBuilder()
                            .addLong("id", Long.valueOf(id))
                            .addDate("date", new Date()).toJobParameters());

        return Response.status(200).entity(user).build();
    }
```

Job Xml:

```
<!-- stored job-meta in memory -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
</bean>

<batch:job id="reportJob">
    <batch:step id="temptask">
        <batch:tasklet ref="abc">
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="customStepListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="customStepListener" class="com.howtodoinjava.service.RunScheduler" />

<bean id="abc" class="com.howtodoinjava.service.CustomTask" />

<bean id="runScheduler" class="com.howtodoinjava.service.RunScheduler" />

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" cron="*/1 * * * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Run scheduler:

```
    @Component
    public class RunScheduler implements StepExecutionListener {

        private static String queryid = null;

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(queryid);
        }

        @Override
        public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution arg0) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepexecute) {
        queryid = stepexecute.getJobExecution().getJobParameters()
                .getString("id");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that two requests to the controller are not running two instances of the job async?

Comment: Yes. More important for me is the scheduling part. If i hit http url in the browser first time than that particular job will be scheduled as per cron expression. If i again hit the url in the browser with different id in the end part than previous scheduled job will be lost and second job will be scheduled only. My requirement is to schedule both the jobs. Sample http request url: [Links] http://localhost:8080/RESTfulDemoApplication/user-management/users/1    and           http://localhost:8080/RESTfulDemoApplication/user-management/users/2

Comment: You aren't actually scheduling anything in the controller.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Any sample code of scheduling the same?